# Gradients of loss with respect to random parameters are the same in pytorch

Tags: pytorch, backpropagation

In the simple code below, I perform a simple linear operation on an input tensor of ones and compute its binary cross-entropy loss considering a vector of zeros as the expected output.
When computing the gradient of the loss with respect to `w`, the rows are the same and equal to the gradient with respect to `b`. This is counter-intuitive since `w` and `b` have random values. What is the reason?

```
n_input, n_output = 5, 3
x = torch.ones(n_input)
y = torch.zeros(n_output) # expected output
w = torch.randn(n_input, n_output, requires_grad=True) 
b = torch.randn(n_output, requires_grad=True)
z = torch.matmul(x,w) + b
loss = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(z, y) 

loss.backward()
print(w.grad)
print(b.grad)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959],
        [0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959],
        [0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959],
        [0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959],
        [0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959]])
tensor([0.2179, 0.4337, 0.1959])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because Your input is **symmetric**.

Imagine the issue from the point of view of a perceptron (You have 3 of them in Your setup):
each input is 1.0 so the weights of a specific neuron don't matter (it is not important from which input You will take as there is 1.0 everywhere).

If You diversify the input, everything works just fine:

```
    n_input, n_output = 5, 3
    x = torch.randn(n_input)
    y = torch.ones(n_output)/2.  # expected output
    w = torch.randn(n_input, n_output, requires_grad=True)
    b = torch.randn(n_output, requires_grad=True)
    z = torch.matmul(x, w) + b

    loss = torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy_with_logits(z, y)
    loss.backward()
    print(w.grad)
    print(b.grad)
```

```
    tensor([[-0.1939,  0.1657, -0.2501],
        [ 0.0561, -0.0480,  0.0724],
        [-0.3162,  0.2703, -0.4079],
        [ 0.0947, -0.0809,  0.1221],
        [-0.0140,  0.0120, -0.0181]])
    tensor([-0.1263,  0.1080, -0.1630])
```

Comment: Right. Indeed, `z1 = w11 + w12 + w13 + w14 + w15 + b1`, so the gradient of `z1` is the same with respect to all variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have a single data point with an input feature size of `5`. If you look at your operation performed you have `z = x@w + b`, then you have a binary cross-entropy from logits against a null label. The binary cross-entropy is defined by:

```
bce = -[y_true*log(σ(y_pred)) + (1 - y_true)*log(1 - σ(y_pred))]
```

The gradient of `z` is written as the partial derivative `dL/dz`, it consists of three elements (same size as `z`) let's say `[dz1, dz2, dz3]`.

To compute the gradients of the weight parameter `w` and the bias parameter `b` we have the following:

```
dL/dw = x.T @ dL/dz
dL/db = dL/dz (with a shape change)
```

Therefore `b.grad` is simply

```
[dz1, dz2, dz3]
```

And, since we have `x` made up of ones, `x.T @ dL/dz` ends up being a matrix with rows equal to `dL/dz` as well, *i.e.* with five rows:

```
[[dz1, dz2, dz3],
 [dz1, dz2, dz3],
 [dz1, dz2, dz3],
 [dz1, dz2, dz3],
 [dz1, dz2, dz3]]
```

Comment: Thanks. That's right, but the other comment is more to the point.

Comment: @Hossein Depends on if you want to get the mathematical proof or an intuitive feel for it :)

Comment: The main point here is that the equality of input elements plays the main role. I agree that it can also be expressed in a more formal way.